# Gatling considers scenario is empty while it's not so

Tags: gatling

Gatling version 3.8.1

I've record a scenario via Gatling recorder, now I want to run it with prompt, but I'm getting `"Scenario RecordedSimulation is empty"` error, while it is not empty. Here are screenshots
[image]
[image]

Did I miss something to make Gatling run my scenario ?

Comment: Indeed, the missing dot is a bug: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4288

Answer (score 0):

The error message does say the simulation class doesn’t contain any code.
It’s saying the scenario named RecordedSimulation is empty, ie it doesn’t have any action chained.

The typical error is to have a missing dot to attach the scenario and its content.

Then, you might be hitting this bug if you are using the recorder: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4288

Answer (score -1):

That's true, it was needed to add this dot (can't understand why Gatling missed it)
[image]

Comment: Please validate my answer then. And Gatling didn't miss anything. Without a dot, the rest of the code is just executed but the return result is not assigned into a reference and is discarded.